# How to implement Auto renewable subscriptions in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I am new to objective c and was wondering how to implement (step by step) auto renewable subscriptions in Objective C in Xcode. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:

http://savvyapps.com/blog/how-setup-test-auto-renewable-subscription-ios-app

The link describes step by step process to setup the autorenewable subscription and also how can you test them.

Comment: Note: This is a swift tutorial, not objective-c

Comment: So the answer is dated 1 year back. Not sure, but may be the blog poster have updated his blog for swift.

Comment: Perhaps; either way it was useful for me as I just converted to Obj-C manually.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw can you please share solution for objective c?